# What Is A Beta Orbiter?

Tags: slang

It's a term for a sociological type, like a 'yuppie', 'baby boomer'. DINK, etc. But what else are they? Scene in a club: My Friend: "I'd like to go over to that table full of girls and talk to them but there's two guys with them. Me: "No worries. Let's go talk to them. Those dudes are just beta orbiters." (Urban Dictionary). I'm looking for something deeper than this that explains more about the dynamics of the beta orbiter's social environment. This might be a gender neutral term but I suppose it's mostly applicable to men.

Comment: I added an example from the Urban Dictionary. But I think their definition just hints at a more involved social implication.

Comment: Space [exploration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploration_of_Mars) _orbiters_ may also be related.

Comment: I don't think so unless single women are on board surrounded by a few hopeful male hangers-on.

Comment: I just discovered a blog that explains in lengthy and grim detail the cruel dynamics of the man-woman relationship and the role of the male Beta orbiter. Aloofguy.blogspot.com. It isn't a pretty picture. I haven't bought the theory completely, but I've leased it with an option to purchase. It all sounds about right.

Answer (score 1):

Probably derived from the terms and concepts of [alpha and beta in the study of animal behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_%28ethology%29).